# Eigenspace, Jordan Canonical form

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ with all eigenvalues equal to $\lambda$, i.e. the characteristic function $c_A(z)=(z-\lambda)^n$.

Denote $F_i=N[(A-\lambda I)^i]$ ($N$ represents the null space).

If $dimF_1=2$, show that \begin{equation}
  dimF_i=\begin{cases}
    i+1, & \text{if $\quad$ $i<n-1$}.\\
    n, & \qquad i\geq n-1.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

My attempt: It is obvious that $F_1 \subset  F_2 \subset \cdots \subset F_n$ and $dimF_n=n$.

Also I tried to simplify and see what happens when $n=3$.

Let $F_1=span \{x,y\}$, $F_3=span \{x,y,z\}$,$\quad$ where $x,y,z$ are linearly independent. Then $(A-\lambda I)^3z=0$, thus $(A-\lambda I)^2z \in F_1$ and $(A-\lambda I)z \in F_2$. I feel here we need to assume that $dimF_2=2$ and contradict it using the fact $x,y,z$ are linearly independent.

For example: \begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&2
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
then $\quad dimF_1=2 \quad F_1=span\{x=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\  0\end{bmatrix},y=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\  1\end{bmatrix}\}, \quad dimF_2=dimF_3=3$. $z=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\  0\end{bmatrix}$,
and note that $(A-\lambda I)^2=0$, thus $dimF_2=3$, and $(A-\lambda I)z=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true without extra conditions.

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$, $\lambda = 0$.

Then $\dim F_1 = 2$ and $\dim F_2 =\dim F_3 = \cdots = 4$.

Comment: yes, I found that we need to know the degree of minimal polynomial in these case.